# Knockout JS Unit testing and ViewModel coupling and dependencies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, jasmine, dependency-management

I'm starting to write unit tests for my js code and I'm newbie in this. We use knockout.js and need test our viewmodels for the project.

Here is the sample:

**Tasks.js file**

```
var yc = yc || {};

yc.TasksVM = function (options) {
    _addTask = function () {
        yc.AddTask.openDialog();
    },

    _paging = myc.PagingVM();

    _instance = {
        addTask: _addTask,
        paging: _paging,
    };

    return _instance;
}
```

**and AddTask.js file**

```
var yc = yc || {};

yc.AddTaskVM = function (options) {
    var 
    _openDialog = function (orderId) {
        $.ajax({
            data: data, type: 'get', url: dialogUrl,
            success: function (dialogContent) {
                // ...
            }
        });
    };

    _instance = {
        openDialog: _openDialog
    };

    return _instance;
}
```

When **I try to use Jasmine to test TasksVM** I get the issue where I need **instantiated** `yc.AddTask.openDialog()` to call `openDialog()`. Also I need to include this file in `<script>` tag to be able to get call. Then, in the `yc.AddTask.openDialog` I need mock the  `$.ajax` call (and also include jQuery in my html).

**My question is about coupling.**

**1.** Is it OK to call `yc.AddTask.<my_function>` inside from `yc.TasksVM`?

From the **.NET world** we deal with this thru **interfaces**. All external dependency we take away and **use only interfaces in the source code**. So we can mock anything inside the code we are testing.

**2.** Is it OK that I need include all these dependent files to my html file runner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Its OK in a smaller Application, but for a complex one with lots of couplings, I would use some kind of EventAggregator to communicate between models.

2) When I Unit test my JS Business logic I always mock away all services and DOM interaction, DOM interaction you get for free with KO since you are only testing the ViewModel which already is decoupled from the DOM (One of the biggest advantages with MVVM if you ask me).

jQuery is a DOM interaction library and you should only use the Service part of it (post, ajax, getJson etc), so what I did for our Unit test was to overwrite $ and jQuery symbols so if any of my fellow devolpers tried to use $("dom") from a ViewModel it would crash in the unit test, a good way of making sure that all dev's are using KO correctly.

In the setup for the unit test just overwrite the method that you want to mock (Pseudo code not Jasmine)

```
$.getJSON = function(url, params, success) {
   assert(1, params.id, "It should call our backend with the correct Id");
   success(mockedData);
};
```

edit: In my project we use Qunit and have a base test "class", it has a teardown so it nulls all mocked functions, this way they cant be called from a different test

Comment: Ok, I understood your point of view. What should I do with my example? It's a piece of our real app I need to cever with tests. How to deal with this external method call?

Comment: You mean have to test it or how to make the actual code less coupled?

Comment: I mean how to test exactly this case. Because it is production code I need write test and then only decouple the code.

Comment: Just override the external call with a mocked function like my example above?